# Threads in asp.net (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-2.0

When a user visits an .aspx page, I need to start some background calculations in a new thread. The results of the calculations need to be stored in the user's Session, so that on a callback, the results can be retrieved. Additionally, on the callback, I need to be able to see what the status of the background calculation is. (E.g. I need to check if the calculation is finished and completed successfully, or if it is still running) How can I accomplish this?

**Questions**

1. How would I check on the status of the thread? Multiple users could have background calculations running at the same time, so I'm unsure how the process of knowing which thread belongs to which user would work.. (though in my scenario, the only thread that matters, is the thread originally started by user A -- and user A does a callback to retrieve/check on the status of that thread).
2. Am I correct in my assumption that passing an HttpSessionState "Session" variable for the user to the new thread, will work as I expect (e.g. I can then add stuff to their Session later).

Thanks. Also I have to say, I might be confused about something but it seems like the SO login system is different now, so I don't have access to my old account.

**Edit**

I'm now thinking about using the approach described in [this article](http://www.devx.com/asp/Article/29617/0/page/3) which basically uses a class and a Singleton to manage a list of threads. Instead of storing my data in the database (and incurring the performance penalty associated with retrieving the data, as well as the extra table, maintenance, etc in the database), I'll probably store the data in my class as well.

**Edit 2**

The approach mentioned in my first edit worked well. Additionally I had timers to ensure the threads, and their associated data, were both cleaned up after the corresponding timers called their cleanup methods. The Objects containing my data and the threads were stored in the Singleton class. For some applications it might be appropriate to use the database for storage but it seemed like overkill for mine, since my data is tied to a specific instance of a page, and is useless outside of that page context.

Comment: There was no change in login system.. anyway you can click "contact us" in the footer and email the team asking to merge your accounts.

Comment: If you can be more specific sour the old account (perhaps find a post), we can fix that. There is no "obvious" single match, but several possibles...

Comment: What sort of work are you doing in the background thread? So long as your tie it to the current somehow, shouldn't have any problems. Rather than checking whether background calculation still running, would it be better to fire another event when it completes?

Comment: @timothyclifford By my understanding of asp.net firing an event would not work because once the user's Response is sent, there is no longer any context with which to communicate. The reason I'm using a background thread to begin with is so that I can send the response, perform some calculation, then the user can retrieve the results of that calculation using an AJAX request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would *not* expect session-state to continue working in this scenario; the worker may have no idea who the user is, and even if it does (or more likely: you capture this data into the worker), no reason to store anything (updating session is a step towards the end of the request pipeline; but if you aren't ***in*** the pipeline...?).

I suspect you might need to store this data separately using some unique property of the user (their id or cn), or invent a GUID otherwise. On a single machine it may suffice to store this in a synchronised dictionary (or similar), but on a farm/cluster you may need to push the data down a layer to your database or state server. And fetch manually.

Comment: Thanks Marc. If it isn't possible to use the Session in this scenario then I suppose I can use a database table and have the background thread store its data there. As for checking on the status of the user's background thread; is there any mechanism to do so? I noticed that C# threads (class=Thread) have an ID property, so I'm looking for that or some similar way to look up the status of the user's thread.